# SQL Merge: Exec SP in matched part

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, merge, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to use the following sql query?

```
MERGE INTO A
USING B
ON (A.ID = B.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    EXEC SP Delete @Id = B.[Id]
```

The SP executes multiple delete statements from different tables. That's why i want to exec a SP in a Merge query.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: this is in MS SQL Server 2012